# Repeated Meta Stack Overflow in Careers Profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

When I add/edit a Stack Exchange site on my Careers page I got repeated a

> Meta Stack Overflow

[image: Repeated]

See this screenshot:

I am using firefox 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's your browser displaying the ALT text of an image it couldn't download. It may be related to our load balancer acting up for a minute (about half an hour ago); in that case, it should resolve itself.

Also note that Firefox 4 is now considered ancient. We don't support it anymore, and neither does Mozilla. You should upgrade ASAP.